# Adding iptable rules from file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian, iptables

I am trying to add iptable rules from a rules file rather than shell. This is what I have tried, but it doesn't seem to take any sort of effect. Is there something wrong with the way I am setting it up?

**iptables.rules**

```
IPT="/sbin/iptables"

# Flush old rules, old custom tables
$IPT --flush
$IPT --delete-chain

# Set default policies for all three default chains
$IPT -P INPUT DROP
$IPT -P FORWARD DROP
$IPT -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

**iptables**

```
#!/bin/bash
/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
```

**Shell commands**

```
ln -s $HOME/config/iptables.rules /etc/iptables.up.rules
ln -s $HOME/config/init/iptables /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables
chmod +x /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables
```

Comment: What are the permissions of your `$HOME`? Perhaps `root` could not read them? Try creating hard-link, to verify.

Comment: Are you trying to make this `iptables` rules persistent across reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the post by miguimon at https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=636996

This is basically a shell script that you can use to enable/disable the firewall rules in the script.  Then, you can run the script from the command line, or from /etc/rc.local.